# Avoid "The Wi-Fi network does not appear to be connected to the internet" prompt on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, iot, nehotspothelper

I am developing an app in Xamarin Forms, which connects to some IoT devices which do not have an Internet connection available.

The IoT device expose a free WIFI hotspot to which the app connects. On iOS side, to perform the connection I use the `NEHotspotConfigurationManager.SharedManager.ApplyConfiguration` method with a `NEHotspotConfiguration` object. This is the part of the code I use to perform the connection:

```
NEHotspotConfiguration configuration = new NEHotspotConfiguration(ssid);
NEHotspotConfigurationManager.SharedManager.ApplyConfiguration(configuration, (NSError error) =>
{
    if (error != null)
    {
         if (error.LocalizedDescription == "already associated.")
         {
             return true;
         }
         else
         {
             return false;
         }
    }
    else
    {
         return true;
    }
});
```

Everything works fine, the app successfully connects the IoT device and I am able to interact with it once the connection is established.
But sometimes a prompt is shown informing that **The Wi-Fi network "name-of-wifi" does not appear to be connected to the internet. Do you want to temporarily use cellular data?**

Is there any way to avoid this prompt to be shown. I read that setting joinOnce to true in the `NEHotspotConfiguration` object could to the trick but, with this flag = true, once the app is put in background the connection with the IoT device is interrupted.

Is it possible to leave `joinOnce` set to `false` and avoid the prompt mentioned above?

Comment: This is up to system design . You could check the wifi status in advance and do something if the network is unavailable  .

Comment: Is there any available Apple documentation about it?

Comment: The internet connection will be always unavailable when connected to these kind of device. I am searching a way to prevent showing that alert, if possible

Comment: As I said , it is up to design (we could not access it) .

Comment: I have the same issue and try to avoid this popup. Do you figure it out?

Comment: @kiritoty No, I didn't figure it out